# FFMPEG Video from images to mp4 in nvidia GPU

Tags: ffmpeg, nvenc, cuvid

I am trying to encode a h264 .mp4 video created from .jpg images using a 1070ti nvidia cuda power, having a a crossfade transition between each image.
I am able to render the video in GPU using the flags -c:v h264_nvenc, I see a short peak in the GPU encoding, but with a long period of computer CPU hight load, I guess preparing the transitioning images. But the image preparation it happens on cpu/ram due the -filter_complex and is quite slow.
This works:

```
ffmpeg.exe, -y, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565957420594_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565957453659_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565957487743_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565957525280_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565957587308_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565957644898_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565957859119_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i,1565959133561_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565959412948_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565959501884_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565959755432_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565959882380_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565960023185_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565960157174_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565960683303_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565961151548_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565961230278_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, 1565961671766_labeled.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, final.jpg, 
-loop, 1, -t, 2.5, -i, final.jpg, 
-c:v, h264_nvenc, -preset, fast, 
-filter_complex, [1]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0.5/TB[f0];
[2]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1.0/TB[f1];
[3]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1.5/TB[f2];
[4]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2.0/TB[f3];
[5]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2.5/TB[f4];
[6]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3.0/TB[f5];
[7]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3.5/TB[f6];
[8]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4.0/TB[f7];
[9]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4.5/TB[f8];
[10]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5.0/TB[f9];
[11]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5.5/TB[f10];
[12]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+6.0/TB[f11];
[13]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+6.5/TB[f12];
[14]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+7.0/TB[f13];
[15]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+7.5/TB[f14];
[16]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8.0/TB[f15];
[17]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8.5/TB[f16];
[18]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+9.0/TB[f17];
[19]fade=d=0.5:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+9.5/TB[f18];
[0][f0]overlay[bg1];
[bg1][f1]overlay[bg2];
[bg2][f2]overlay[bg3];
[bg3][f3]overlay[bg4];
[bg4][f4]overlay[bg5];
[bg5][f5]overlay[bg6];
[bg6][f6]overlay[bg7];
[bg7][f7]overlay[bg8];
[bg8][f8]overlay[bg9];
[bg9][f9]overlay[bg10];
[bg10][f10]overlay[bg11];
[bg11][f11]overlay[bg12];
[bg12][f12]overlay[bg13];
[bg13][f13]overlay[bg14];
[bg14][f14]overlay[bg15];
[bg15][f15]overlay[bg16];
[bg16][f16]overlay[bg17];
[bg17][f17]overlay[bg18];
[bg18][f18]overlay[v], 
-map, [v], -movflags, +faststart, output.mp4
```

I am trying to do all work in the GPU, theoretically I can encode all images in GPU memory using in each -i the flags "-hwaccel cuvid -c:v mjpeg_cuvid" I receive the following error:

```
[mjpeg_cuvid @ 00000000024ef980] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 1:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Is there a way to load images in the GPU with the "fade" flag applied ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I was having a similar issue, but I was just stitching frames together (no transition between frames), and adding the "-hwaccel cuvid -c:v mjpeg_cuvid" flags fixed it for me. The complete command that's working for me is: `ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v mjpeg_cuvid -framerate 29.97 -i dji_0099_%04d.jpg -c:v h264_nvenc output2.mp4`